# Two identical graphs producing different local transitivity

Tags: r, igraph

I have two identical graphs:

```
a<-graph.lattice(dimvector = 100, length = NULL, dim = NULL, nei = 5,
              directed = FALSE, mutual = FALSE, circular = TRUE)

b<-read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22681355/graph2.csv",head=T,sep=';')

b<-as.matrix(b)
b<-graph.data.frame(b)
```

Looking at `str(a)` and `str(b)` shows that these are identical networks.
Now when I check their local transitivity, I get different outputs.

```
transitivity(b, type=c("local"))

 [1] 0.1578947

transitivity(a, type=c("local"))

 [1] 0.6666667
```

What is causing the difference? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What package(s) are you using?

Comment: Yes, you are doing something wrong, the two graphs are not the same.

Comment: Btw. if you just type in `b` and `a` to see the basic properties of your graphs, you already see that they are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two graphs are not identical; `a` is undirected (since you said so) while `b` isn't (since you did not specify `directed=FALSE` in the `graph.data.frame` call).

Comment: even if I specify directed=FALSE in the graph.data.frame, the local transitivity is still 0.157... do you get something different?

Comment: Yup; `transitivity(a, type=c("local"))` and `transitivity(b, type=c("local"))` both give me a vector of length 100 where every element is 0.666667. Besides, note that your graph `b` has 1000 edges while `a` has only 500, since your CSV file lists every edge in both direction. You are probably missing `b <- simplify(b)`.